# Is there an equivalent to Julia's eval(parse(String)) in python?

Tags: python, julia, metaprogramming

Disclaimer: New to stack overflow. In the Julia language the `eval(parse())` ability comes in very useful. Example: `eval(parse("x = 5"))`. I'm wondering if there is an equivalent in python, I get the consensus that this is a no. If it is a no why? Surely it would be a useful addition to the language.

Comment: I'm not sure why this was closed; it seems like it could be a useful discussion? I was about to post this before it was closed: ---------------------

In python, this is just `eval("expression")`:
https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/eval

The difference is that Python does not (as far as I know) have a built-in, first-class structure for representing _parsed expressions_, which julia of course makes heavy use of for metaprogramming.  --------------- EDIT: Ah i see now it was closed as a duplicate. I guess that makes sense. StackOverflow is strict! :)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow :)